# How to setup username , password access for RHEL Ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I followed the following blog post to set up passwod access for ec2 instnce.

https://coderwall.com/p/j5nk9w

am not able to log in using password. Am getting the following error wheni restart the sshd service.

```
Stopping sshd:                                             [FAILED]
Starting sshd: /etc/ssh/sshd_config line 150: Bad yes/no argument: noUseDNS
                                                       [FAILED]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you have a syntax error in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file OR you used an option which it does not support (noUseDNS).

The link you have mentioned does the right thing. You are doing something different from what the link suggests.